# Redirect from https:// to https://www using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I am trying to get my site to redirect all traffic to https://www.mylittleblackebook.com no matter how the URL is typed into the browser. There are six ways someone can type the URL into a browser. They are:

1. https://www.mylittleblackebook.com
2. https://mylittleblackebook.com
3. http://www.mylittleblackebook.com
4. http://mylittleblackebook.com
5. www.mylittleblackebook.com
6. mylittleblackebook.com

All of these URL’s will work **EXCEPT FOR** the second one. I cannot get the .htaccess file to redirect https:/mylittleblackebook.com to https://www.mylittleblackebook.com. Here is the code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# require SSL without mod_ssl
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This code works for 5 out of the 6 ways. Can anyone tell me how to get it to work for all of them?

Thank you for taking the time to look this over.

Comment: Please note that points 5 and 6 are `http://` by default. Also, i can't see any error in your code, your point 2 should be working as expected like other points. Try to clear your browser's cache and try again (maybe an old rule in cache causes the problem)

Comment: I thought that might be the problem also, but i have cleared the cache, and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct, not sure why it doesn't work.  I would try this instead, it's in the opposite order and a bit different:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R,NE]
```